# Eclipse showing two THIS$0 fields for a nested class (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nested, extends

I have been facing an odd phenomena that I don't quite understand. I have an abstract class that is extended by several other classes. the abstract class is a type of special collection and it has a nested abstract iterator class that fits it. Every class that extends the abstract collection class, also has a nester iterator class that extends the orginal abstract iterator.

The abstract class is something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractMultiCollection<T> {

    public AbstractMultiCollection() {
    ...
    }

    MultiIterator<T> iterator();

    public abstract class AbstractMultiIterator {
        public AbstractMultiIterator() {
        ...
        }
```

The extending classes are something like this:

```
public class MajorityMultiCollection<T> extends AbstractMultiCollection<T> {
...
    public MultiIterator<T> iterator() {
        return new MajorityIterator();
    }
    ...     

    public class MajorityIterator extends AbstractMultiIterator {

        public MajorityIterator() {
        super();
        ...
        }

        public T next() {
        ...
        }
```

Simply put, the collections extend the abstract collection and their nested iterators extend the nested abstract iterator.

I have two problems that I don't understand and would appreciate clarification on:

1. When I debug my code, the "return new MajorityIterator();" lines raise a "Source Not Found" error and "ClassNotFound" exception in the eclipse debugger and a bunch of "ClassLoaderExt" exceptions that I don't understand.
2. I noticed that every "MajorityIterator" has two "This$0" fields, containing the collection he belongs to. one is null at first, but receives the collection once I invoke the "super();" builder.

I failed to find the reason for this, can anyone clarify? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What `this$0` is: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue207.html

Answer (score 4):

Actually having two `this` references makes sense. One thing most people do not realize is *how* the Java compiler implements non-static nested classes:

- It implicitly adds a new field with the type of the outer class, lets call it `outer$object`.
- It implicitly adds a new argument for the outer class object to all constructors to fill in that field. Incidentally, that means that the default constructor of the inner class actually has a parameter, which makes using it via reflection significantly more complex.
- It implicitly creates constructors and methods with wider visibility to get around any accessibility issues if e.g. the inner class is declared `private`.

Since the `outer$object` field needs to have the same type as the outer class, one will be added each time a nested class inherits from a class that is *not* nested within the same outer class.

Personally, I tend to avoid non-static non-anonymous inner classes, in order to keep everything explicitly on the surface, rather than let the compiler make a mess out of things...

Answer (score 3):

A `MajorityIterator` object will indeed have two `this$0` fields:

- One (implicitly declared in `MajorityIterator`) for the reference to the enclosing instance of `MajorityMultiCollection`
- One (implicitly declared in `AbstractMultiIterator`) for the reference to the enclosing instance of `AbstractMultiCollection`. This will be null until the `super()` call, as it'll be set in the constructor.

You might find it clearer to make these *static* nested classes, and explicitly pass in the reference to the enclosing instance instead - I suspect you only *want* one reference, and it'll be simpler to reason about.